# React native beacon manager on background- Receives empty beacon array even when I'm near the beacon

Tags: android, react-native, altbeacon

React native beacon manager - Receives empty beacon array even when I'm near the beacon.

The `react-native-beacons-manager` is the rn library im using and most likely its using the AltBeacon Android lib

I added background service library which is `react-native-background-actions`

I added foreground service as well which is `@supersami/rn-foreground-service`

My `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```xml
        <service android:name="com.asterinet.react.bgactions.RNBackgroundActionsTask" android:foregroundServiceType="location|connectedDevice" tools:node="replace">
            <meta-data android:name="longScanForcingEnabled" android:value="true"/>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.supersami.foregroundservice.ForegroundService" android:foregroundServiceType="location|connectedDevice" tools:node="replace"></service>
        <service android:name="com.supersami.foregroundservice.ForegroundServiceTask" android:foregroundServiceType="location|connectedDevice" tools:node="replace"></service>
            <service android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService" android:foregroundServiceType="connectedDevice"
            tools:node="replace">
            <meta-data android:name="longScanForcingEnabled" android:value="true"/>
        </service>
```

My code on background task looks like this:

```js
BackgroundService.start(()=>{
    Beacons.detectIBeacons()
    Beacons.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true)

    Beacons.setForegroundScanPeriod(FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD)
    Beacons.setBackgroundScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD)
    Beacons.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD)

    ...ommitted beacon monitoring, ranging and determine state

}, options)
```

My code on foreground task looks like this:

```js
ReactNativeForegroundService.add_task(() => 
{
Beacons.detectIBeacons()
    Beacons.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true)

    Beacons.setForegroundScanPeriod(FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD)
    Beacons.setBackgroundScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD)
    Beacons.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD)

    ...omitted beacon monitoring, ranging and determine state
}
```

...omitted foreground task starting the notification

This is the forked lib I'm currently playing with rn [forked-react-native-beacons-manager](https://github.com/dmontecillo/react-native-beacons-manager)

Please advise on what i missed?
Thanks

Comment: Has you app been granted location permission?  check Settings -> Apps -> Your App -> Permissions -> Location.  Also see a full troubleshooting list here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection-trouble.html

Comment: yes 'Allow all the time' is selected. Im using Gimbal beacons in foreground it works well but when I minimize the app a few minutes later RegionDid exit triggers even though the beacon is beside me. I as well copied whats currently in here https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html unfortunately issue still persist.

Comment: What device make, model and os version are you using for testing?  Do you actually see a foreground service notification?

Comment: Hello @davidgyoung im using OS 9(Oppo) and 10(Xiaomi). But most of the time im testing 10. Though latest changes I made with my forked library it works well now but still testing is still in progress from our test team and I am awaiting if there are issues.

Comment: @davidgyoung sorry, yes I added a foreground service notification when starting to monitor beacon and disable it when monitoring stops. (I only used monitoring)

Comment: Be aware that Oppo and Xiaomi have problematic customizations to kill apps running in the background https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi

Comment: Yep, I read that as well. Although I tested the example app and modified it a bit to make sure the code can run in the background and it works well so far. I even force closed the app and the beacon scanner is still able to detect when i turned on/off the beacon itself.